# Prove that if $(M,\ d)$ is compact, every infinite subset of $M$ has a limit point

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Prove that if $(M,\ d)$ is compact, every infinite subset of $M$ has a limit point.

Definitions:

> $P$ is **compact** iff every sequence in $P$ has a subsequence that
>   converges to a point in $P$.
>
> Let $A$ be any subset of $(M,\ d)$. $x\in M$ is a **limit point** of $A$ iff
>    there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of points with $x_n\in A\ \forall
>  n$, $x_n\ne x$ and $x_n\to x$.

**My attempt:**

Let $M$ be compact. Let $A$ be an infinite subset of $M$.

Let $\{x_n\}\subset A$ be composed of *different* elements of $A$ in any order. We know we can find such a sequence because $A$ is infinite.

$\{x_n\}\subset M$

Since $M$ is compact, $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{x_{n_i}\}$ that converges to a point $x\in M$. We claim that $x$ is a limit point of $A$.

Form a new sequence from $\{x_{n_i}\}$ after removing all the terms are equal to $x$. Since the terms of $\{x_{n_i}\}$ are all different, there can be at most one such term. The terms of this new sequence lie in $A$, are never equal to $x$ and converge to $x$. Thus, by our definition, $x$ is a limit point of $A$.

So, $A$ has a limit point.

QED

Could someone please go through this proof and tell me if I've missed something?

Comment: Why did you remark *different* in the proof's first part? And what does "ordered" mean in this context? . Observe that your final phrases in that proof aren't so sound: "...by our definition $\;x\;$ is a limit p[oint of $\;A\;$ . So, $\;A\;$ has a limit point" (??)

Comment: In fact, what you want to prove is almost exactly the same as what you've defined as "compact" ...

Comment: I'm just saying that no term in my sequence is repeated. By order, I'm referring to referring to the order of elements in the sequence.

Comment: (1) Why would you say such a thing? You are thus limiting the generality and the claim must be true for **any** infinite sequence. (2) What order can there be in some general metric space? For example, the complex numbers $\;\Bbb C\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio What needs to be arbitrary in the proof is $A$. I see nothing wrong with choosing an sequence of distinct elements from $A$ if $A$ is chosen arbitrarily to begin with, which it was here.

Comment: Proof looks good to me.

Comment: @aduh You are right: it is $\;A\;$ which must be arbitrary. The two points though remain, but (1) no need to worry about "different", and (2) You cannot talk of any order in a general metric space.

Comment: @DonAntonio As Thomas pointed out, the relevant ordering is on $\mathbb{N}$, not $M$.

Comment: @aduh That doesn't seem to make sense: the index set is $\;\Bbb N\;$ , yet it has nothing to do with the order of the *elements* .

Comment: @DonAntonio I'll try one more time. It makes sense to talk about the order of the elements _in a sequence_ even if $M$ has no order. Formally, given a sequence, the order is defined by $x_m < x_n$ iff $m < n$. Nothing mysterious about this.

Comment: @aduh Really? That is what you, or the OP, meant? Oh, well...

Comment: @DonAntonio I think it's a charitable reading of the OP.